# Debugging Grocery_CRUD Callbacks

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have seen many people referring to the usage of `call_user_func()` to debug the problems in a `Grocery_CRUD` callback, but unfortunately no one has come off with a complete example to actually how to use it like where to to place a call to the test function `[just_a_test()]` in the controller an example of what I am trying to discover is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201343/debugging-in-grocery-crud).

I am unable to understand where do we call this

1. `just_a_test()`,
2. how are we able to pass on the desired parameters using `call_user_func(array($this,'insert_coupon_codes'));` when there are no para's being passed to the `just_a_test()`?
3. how come the `insert_coupon_codes` will be able to get the desired para's?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Grocery CRUD add the parameters automatically from the library. You are not able (till now at version 1.1.8) to add more parameters at your callback.</strike>

**Update:** At the latest version of Grocery CRUD now you CAN pass as many parameters as you need. This is a functionality that PHP is offering from version PHP 5.4 or later. More specifically with the `use` keyword. More specifically if you have the callback `callback_after_insert`: 
usually you would use it like this:

```
$crud->callback_after_insert(function ($post_array,$primary_key) {
    // Your code here
});
```

From PHP 5.4 version and later you can add more parameters with the `use` so for example you could have:

```
$my_variable = 'test';
$another_variable = 'hello';
$crud->callback_after_insert(function ($post_array,$primary_key) use ($my_variable, $another_variable) {
    // Now you can use the variables $my_variable and $another_variable at your callback
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do so in newest version?